# Debugging Java Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, debugging, garbage-collection, jsoup, out-of-memory

I'm still a relatively new programmer, and an issue I keep having in Java is Out of Memory Errors. I don't want to increase the memory using -Xmx, because I feel that the error is due to poor programming, and I want to improve my coding rather than rely on more memory.

The work I do involves processing lots of text files, each around 1GB when compressed. The code I have here is meant to loop through a directory where new compressed text files are being dropped. It opens the second most recent text file (not the most recent, because this is still being written to), and uses the Jsoup library to parse certain fields in the text file (fields are separated with custom delimiters: "|nTa|" designates a new column and "|nLa|" designates a new row).

I feel there should be no reason for using a lot of memory. I open a file, scan through it, parse the relevant bits, write the parsed version into another file, close the file, and move onto the next file. I don't need to store the whole file in memory, and I certainly don't need to store files that have already been processed in memory.

I'm getting errors when I start parsing the second file, which suggests that I'm not dealing with garbage collection. Please have a look at the code, and see if you can spot things that I'm doing that mean I'm using more memory than I should be. I want to learn how to do this right so I stop getting memory errors!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class ParseHTML {

    public static int commentExtractField = 3;
    public static int contentExtractField = 4;
    public static int descriptionField = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File directoryCompleted = null;     
        File filesCompleted[] = null;

        while(true) {

            // find second most recent file in completed directory  
            directoryCompleted = new File(args[0]);     
            filesCompleted = directoryCompleted.listFiles();

            if (filesCompleted.length > 1) {

                TreeMap<Long, File> timeStamps = new TreeMap<Long, File>(Collections.reverseOrder());

                for (File f : filesCompleted) {
                    timeStamps.put(getTimestamp(f), f);
                }

                File fileToProcess = null;

                int counter = 0;

                for (Long l : timeStamps.keySet()) {
                    fileToProcess = timeStamps.get(l);
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }   

                // start processing file
                GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = null;

                if (fileToProcess != null) {
                    gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToProcess));
                }

                else {
                    System.err.println("No file to process!");
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(gzipInputStream);
                scanner.useDelimiter("\\|nLa\\|");

                GZIPOutputStream output = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("parsed/" + fileToProcess.getName()));

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(scanner.next()); 
                    scanner2.useDelimiter("\\|nTa\\|");

                    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();

                    while(scanner2.hasNext()) {
                        row.add(scanner2.next());   
                    }

                    for (int index = 0; index < row.size(); index++) {
                        if (index == commentExtractField ||
                                index == contentExtractField ||
                                index == descriptionField) {
                            output.write(jsoupParse(row.get(index)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        }

                        else {
                            output.write(row.get(index).getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        }   

                        String delimiter = "";

                        if (index == row.size() - 1) {
                            delimiter = "|nLa|";
                        }

                        else {
                            delimiter = "|nTa|";
                        }

                        output.write(delimiter.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    }
                }

                output.finish();
                output.close();
                scanner.close();
                gzipInputStream.close();


            }
        }
    }

    public static Long getTimestamp(File f) {
        String name = f.getName();
        String removeExt = name.substring(0, name.length() - 3);
        String timestamp = removeExt.substring(7, removeExt.length());
        return Long.parseLong(timestamp);
    }

    public static String jsoupParse(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 4) {
            return s;
        }

        else {
            return Jsoup.parse(s).text();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that when I finish with objects, they are destroyed and not using any resources? For example, each time I close the GZIPInputStream, GZIPOutputStream and Scanner, how can I make sure they're completely destroyed?

For the record, the error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:572)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:203)
at org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState$47.read(TokeniserState.java:1171)
at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.read(Tokeniser.java:42)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:101)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:53)
at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:24)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:44)
at ParseHTML.jsoupParse(ParseHTML.java:125)
at ParseHTML.main(ParseHTML.java:81)
```

Comment: from the file sizes that you have provided, i think that increasing memory would be quite necessary

Comment: yes, but I'm already using -Xmx1501m

Comment: and what makes you think that is anywhere near to sufficient?

Comment: 1.) the small talk: surround using of outputstreams, inputstreams and alike with try/catch/finally and close them in finally block. 2.) you must use profiling to know how it grows and who is really using the resources, that's the truth!

Comment: just to make sure, the main while loop doesn't end at all? In case the file that's still being written hadn't finished by the time last finished file is parsed, we are going to parse it again? Not related to the problem at all, can save some CPU though.

Comment: Also wondering, why storing in an ArrayList and then going through it one by one? Parse it as you read it, use the index on every read for jsoup and non-jsoup writing(pardon my language here). When scanner.hasnext() is not true, end the loop and write the last delimiter. Definite optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This issue was fixed in JSoup 1.6.2

It looks to me like it's probably a bug in the JSoup parser that you're using...at present the [documentation for JSoup.parse()](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string) has a warning "BETA: if you do get an exception raised, or a bad parse-tree, please file a bug." Which suggests they aren't confident that it's completely safe for use in production code.

I also found several bug reports mentioning out of memory exceptions, [one of which](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/159) suggests that it's due to parse error objects being held statically by JSoup, and that downgrading from JSoup 1.6.1 to 1.5.2 may be a work-around.

Comment: I will try downgrading, thank you. It is a bug in jsoup, I'm sure now

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say why, but I'm pleased to say that my issue was resolved by downgrading to JSoup 1.5.2

Answer (score 3):

I haven't spent very long analysing your code (nothing stands out), but a good general-purpose start would be to familiarise yourself with the free [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) tool. [This](http://www.gemini5201314.net/bi/profiling_with_visualvm.html) is a reasonable guide to its use, though there are many more articles.

There are better commercial profilers in my opinion - JProfiler for one - but it will at the very least show you what objects/classes most memory is being assigned to, and possibly the method stack traces that caused that to happen. More simply it shows you heap allocation over time, and you can use this to judge whether you are failing to clear something or whether it is an unavoidable spike.

I suggest this rather than looking at the specifics of your code because it is a useful diagnostic skill to have.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look. i agree that i need to be able to use it

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if your parse is failing because you have bad HTML (e.g. unclosed tags, unpaired quotes or whatnot) being parsed?  You could do a output /println to see how far you are getting in the document if at all. The Java library may not understand the end of the document /file before running out of memory.

parse
 public static Document parse(String html) Parse HTML into a Document. As no base URI is specified, absolute URL detection relies on the HTML including a  tag.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what's going on but two things come to my mind.

1) In some weird circumstances (depending on the input file), the following loop might load the entire file into memory:

```
while(scanner2.hasNext()) {
    row.add(scanner2.next());
}
```

2) By looking at the stackTrace it seems that the jsoupParse is the problem. I believe that this line `Jsoup.parse(s).text();` loads `s` into memory first and depending on the string size (that again depends on the particular file input) this might cause the `OutOfMemoryError`

Maybe a combination of the two points above is the issue. Again, it's hard to tell by just looking at the code..

Does this happen always with the same file? Did you check the input content and the custom delimiters in it?

Comment: I can confirm that this is definitely a jsoup issue, and it always happens with the same file. Tomorrow I'll try to figure out what it's having trouble parsing. Interestingly, it doesn't seem to be just down to string length, as there are other longer strings that it parses without issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is not in JSoup code, we can do some memory optimization. In example, `ArrayList<String> row` could be stripped, as it holds all parsed lines in memory, but only one line needed for parsing.

Inner loop with `row` removed:

```
//Caution! May contain obvious bugs!
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String scanStr = scanner.next();

    //manually count of rows to replace 'row.size()'
    int rowCount = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while ((offset = scanStr.indexOf("|nTa|", offset)) >= 0) {
        rowCount++;
        offset++;
    }
    rowCount++;

    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(scanStr);
    scanner2.useDelimiter("\\|nTa\\|");

    int index = 0;
    while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
        String curRow = scanner2.next();

        if (index == commentExtractField
               || index == contentExtractField
               || index == descriptionField) {
            output.write(jsoupParse(curRow).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } else {
            output.write(curRow.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }

        String delimiter = "";
        if (index == rowCount - 1) {
            delimiter = "|nLa|";
        } else {
            delimiter = "|nTa|";
        }

        output.write(delimiter.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```